# Spring-MVC: Programmatic API for Building REST Resources like in Jersey?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

The standard way for creating REST resources both in JAX-RS and Spring MVC is to use annotations. Jersey provides an alternative to using annotations, which is called [Programmatic API for Building Resources](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/resource-builder.html). This can be used to create REST resources dynamically at runtime, for example from user input or configuration. With the annotations approach, in contrast, creating a new REST resource requires the usual develop/build/deploy cycle.

Is there an equivalent API for building REST resources programmatically **in Spring MVC**? I'm looking for working example code like in the Programmatic Hello World example of the Jersey user guide.

Comment: Why don't use both Spring and Jersey? https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp

Comment: Spring still actively supports Java6, which I need. Jersey doesn't. [Jersey abandoned Java6 support starting with release 2.7](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html#d0e560).